# How to show that $\int_{\Omega} (-\Delta u -f)vdx =0 $ this implies $-\Delta u -f=0$?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve the one question where I want to prove that $u $ satisfies
\begin{equation*}
-\Delta u =f~~~~ in~\Omega\\
u=0~~~~~~on ~~~~\Gamma
\end{equation*}
I proved upto the $\int_{\Omega} (-\Delta u -f)vdx =0 $ where $v \in V$ and $V=\{v: v~ is~ continuous ~on ~\Omega,~\frac{\partial~v}{\partial~x_1}~ and ~\frac{\partial~v}{\partial~x_2}~are ~piecewise~continuous~on~\Omega~and~v=0~on ~~\Gamma\} $ and $u$ is twice continuously differentiable function.

Now, I want to show that $-\Delta u -f=0$.

I proved the same question in 1D by contradiction, but not sure how to prove this one in 2D. Can anyone give some hints to solve this question?

Comment: Have you shown that for all such $v$? If you have then consider proof by contradiction again. If $-\Delta u -f \neq 0$ can you find a $v$ such that $\int_\Omega (-\Delta u -f) v dx \neq 0?$

Comment: @JackT In a 1D I find that v is positive in a subinterval this implies that integral is non zero that makes the contradiction. How do I show that $v$ is positive in 2D?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of contradiction, suppose that $-\Delta u -f\neq 0$. You have that $-\Delta u -f$ is continuous since $u$ is twice continuously differentiable (I expect you also have $f$ continuous otherwise there's no way to show $-\Delta u =f$). Since $-\Delta u -f \neq 0$ there exists some point $x_0\in \Omega$ for which $-\Delta u (x_0)-f(x_0) \neq 0$. Without loss of generality assume $-\Delta u(x_0)-f(x_0)>0$. By continuity, there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $-\Delta u-f>0$ in $B_\varepsilon (x_0)$ (the ball of radius $\varepsilon$ centred at $x_0$). Pick a non-zero smooth function $v:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ such that $v \geqslant 0$ in $\Omega$ and $v=0$ in $\Omega \setminus B_\varepsilon (x_0)$. Then $v \in V$ and$$\int_\Omega (-\Delta u-f) v \, dx =\int_{B_\varepsilon (x_0)} (-\Delta u-f) v \, dx>0 . $$ This is a contradiction.